# Python exe. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, oracle, exe, python-oracledb

I've created a python exe file which runs successfully but when I copy and run that exe file in a remote desktop. It gives this error:

```
Error timestamp: 16082023_044916
Error message: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_to_email_F.py", line 160, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

What could be the issue here ?
Moreover, the remote desktop doesn't have python or any of it's dependencies installed.

The exe file is connecting to an oracle database and extracting some data from there.
The details of what my exe actually does:

> [Python Script to extract data from Database and use it to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76903654/python-script-to-extract-data-from-database-and-use-it-to-email)

Comment: are you sure the machine on which this exe runs can connect to the DB host?

Comment: yes, I've tested many times and it works. I'm getting the email but the same exe is not running in the remote desktop. I'm not sure if it's a port issue or socket issue. Or maybe something else I'm confused.

Comment: Let's say you tested on machine A, when you connect to A thru remote desktop, the same program does not work?

Comment: How did you create the exe?  What API are you using to connect to the DB?

Comment: I'm using cx_Freeze to create exe. I use python oracledb to connect to Oracle Database

Comment: @gsalem no no, I tested on machine A, then I copied that exe (with folder path changed according to machine B) to machine B(remote desktop). Then it shows this above error.

Comment: And are you sure that the remote desktop sees the db server the same way as the one you tested on?

Comment: Yes. I am sure.